# How can I import so file as a module without using ctype Linux?

Tags: python, linux, module, shared-libraries

**File structure** under folder `/home/cyan/TEMP`

```
test.py
  
lib
 |--libc_test_module.so
 
c_test_module.cc
 
CMakeLists.txt
```

**test.py**

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/cyan/TEMP/lib") 
import c_test_module
```

**c_test_module.cc**

```
#include <Python.h>

int c_test_function(int a) {
    return a + 1;
}

static PyObject * _c_test_function(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    int _a;
    int res;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "i", &_a))
        return NULL;
    res = c_test_function(_a);
    return PyLong_FromLong(res);
}


/*  define functions in module */
static PyMethodDef TestMethods[] =
{
     {"c_test_function", _c_test_function, METH_VARARGS,
         "this is a c_test_function"},
     {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};


static struct PyModuleDef c_test_module = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "c_test_module", "Some documentation",
    -1,
    TestMethods
};
PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_c_test_module(void) {
    PyObject *module;
    module = PyModule_Create(&c_test_module);
    if(module==NULL) return NULL;
    /* IMPORTANT: this must be called */
    import_array();
    if (PyErr_Occurred()) return NULL;
    return module;
}
```

**Error**

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'c_test_module'
```

**Question**

I don't want to use `ctype` module to import `.so` file. Instead, I wonder if there is a way to import this file as a module directly.

Comment: Is that an `.so` containing a compiled module, is it some arbitrary compiled code?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I added the `.cc` file with the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a `setup.py` file:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
import numpy

def main():
    setup(name="c_test_module",
          version="1.0.0",
          description="Python interface for the c_test_module C library function",
          author="cyan",
          author_email="xxx@gmail.com",
          ext_modules=[Extension("c_test_module", ["c_test_module.cc"],
                                include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()])],
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now it works to import `c_test_module` and call the functions.